# How to compute the max. speedup achievable of parallel program?

Tags: parallel-computing, performance

I was given the following problem to solve:

Consider a system that has 128 compute units of the same type. Suppose that a program runs for 1025 time units on a single compute unit. The total amount of serial work for this program is 1 time unit. Compute the maximum speedup achievable for the given system.

I am confused about whether to use Ahmadhl's, Gustafson's law, or neither. Also, what is confusing are the given numbers - the program runs serially for 1025 time units, but only 1 time unit is the total amount of serial work - so that means that 1024 time units are parallelizable?

Comment: Did you able to solve this question? I also need this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You understand the problem correctly; 1024 units are parallelizable. To calculate speedup, you can divide the serial runtime by the parallel runtime (no laws required). Or plug into the version of Amdahl's law that actually uses the number of processors (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37335032/5039395).